# Git Remove commits from a project fork

Tags: git, github, rebase

So, I forked a project on Github, and made 2 commits. I also pushed these commits to my fork.

At the same time, the upstream project also had 2 commits.

Let's say at the time of forking, both the branches are at head A

`A`

and I made my two commits B and C and pushed them into my fork

`A - B - C`

and upstream made commits D and E

`A - D - E`

In my clone repo of the fork, I fetched from upstream, so the state is

```
A - D - E
  \ 
    B - C
```

Then I did a rebase, which brought the state to

```
A - D - E
  \ 
    B - C - D' - E'
```

Now, I want to make it in my fork so that D and E never existed and the head is at E'. I am the only one using my fork.

I checked several other answers here and I don't see any questions that have this problem of multiple heads(E and E').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've left out of your picture are the *refs* - branches and tags (and remote branch refs, and potentially a few other things).

When you rebase, if you have a branch checked out (or specify to check a branch out at the start of the rebase), the default behavior is to move the checked-out branch ref to the rewritten commits.  The original commits always still exist; but if no refs still point to them, default log output won't show them.

However, one ref surely still points to them: the remote branch ref for the branch you rewrite.  This will be corrected when you push your updates to the origin.  This will have to be a "forced" push (`git push -f`), but since you are the only user of the repo that shouldn't matter.

If other branches still point at the original commits, you can use `git reset` to move them to the new commits.

```
git checkout branch
git reset <new-commit-id>
```

If branches point to other commits from which the original commits are reachable, then those commits would have to also be rewritten.  That's a bigger topic so let us know if it applies.

Similarly with tags, if they point to the original commits you could move them (`git tag -f ...`).

Comment: You are right. I checked the tags now and upstream/master is at C, origin/master is at E and in my local, the head and master are at E'. Note that D' and E' are not pushed. When I tried `git push -f`, git threw up `fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>`. What I finally want is to have my origin/master at E' and for D and E to disappear. If I understand you correctly, D and E will always be there, but won't appear in the log?

Comment: Do you think `git -f push origin HEAD:master` is the right way to go to achieve this?

Comment: I would check out the branch you want to push, and then just `git push -f` (assuming you normally just `git push`).  But there are many ways to do it, and your preferences may differ from mine.

Comment: There is only one branch in my case(master), and the force push from the above command worked. Github also shows only D' and E' commits in the commit history, which I belive is from the `log` command, like you explained not showing the commits D and E.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned you have - your forked branch - Lets call it as 'Origin' at A-B-C- status (Assuming its push to your Origin),

Now Main Branch (Call it as 'upstream') has few changes A-D-E, So you have to do is ,pull code from upstream and if you are using Eclipse/or Local,  you will have your code ( A-B-C ++ D-E) if you don't have any conflict, push it to your Origin branch, so your repo will be in Sync & then you can also make pull request for your Changes which are B-C ,

Now your Upstream which is main branch and your Origin which is Forked branch are even.